# Windows Phone 8 to Windows 10 mobile upgrade and downgrade problem

Tags: 8.1, update, insider-preview

I have a Lumia 535, and I upgraded it to Windows 10 mobile.

After the upgrade, none of my previous applications was present except for People and Phone. Interesting, this behavior also applied for the Setting  app: it was showing the message "You need to download this app from Store" but I was unable to download the application. 
Also, the phone was getting too hot.

So I decided to move back to Windows Phone 8. I tried by pressing the power and volume button and after the vibration, the volume down, power and volume up buttons to start the downgrade process.

Now I am facing serious problem. The phone is showing rolling gears and after some time, when I put the phone in charging, it restarts, but it always shows rolling gears on the display.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you tried using the [Software recovery tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987)?

Answer (score 2):

you need to know that you have upgraded your phone to Windows Phone 10 and hard resetting won't take you to Windows 8.1. It would still be WP 10.

I am not sure about the first question of why only two application were present, but here's how you can roll back to Windows 8.1 Denim update / the firmware with which your phone was shipped.

Make sure you have charged your phone. Download the Lumia Software recovery tool from Microsoft website:  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=522381. and install it.

Connect your phone and follow the procedures mentioned on the screen. Once, the recovery tool detect your phone, it will just download the firmware and flash your phone with it. So you will be back to Windows PHone 8.1/

Imp: You must not disconnect your phone in the middle of the process. So, make sure to keep your laptop and phone fully charged. 
It will take around 1.5 GB of data bandwidth.

Source: [Return to Windows Phone 8.1 from Windows 10 Technical Preview](http://www.windowsphonesearch.com/2015/07/Return-to-Windows-Phone-8-1-from-Windows-10-technical-preview.html)